# Getting Chi-Square statistics in proc surveylogistic

Tags: sas, logistic-regression

per Default proc surveylogistic displays an F test in the "testing the null hypothesis /beta = 0 " output. Can I somehow change that to a Chi-Square Test?

Usually I use proc logistics but this time I have a cluster variable and to my knowledge proc logistic cant handle those.
In the documentation I read the F and Chi-Square test are equivallent but I get different results for the significance tests (although the point estimates for intercept and my independent variable are the same) to proc logistic for the same analysis.
I also tried using the df=infinity option but the name just changes the value stays the same.

Regards

Comment: Please show your code at minimum. Did you try the CHISQ + DF=INFINITY option on the MODEL statement as per the docs? https://documentation.sas.com/?cdcId=pgmsascdc&cdcVersion=9.4_3.3&docsetId=statug&docsetTarget=statug_surveylogistic_syntax12.htm&locale=en

Comment: Please review the guidelines here on how to ask a question on StackOverflow [ask]. Your question, as posted, does not follow these guidelines.